# CMake not recognizing FORTRAN source in mixed C++/FORTRAN program

Tags: c++, cmake, fortran

I'm moving one of my projects over to CMake (because of the ease of syntax) that I used to use autotools (autoconf, automake, etc). I've run into a slight issue with CMake not recognizing that I have FORTRAN code in my source tree.

One of the libraries I build depends both on C++ and FORTRAN source code. I've used the following syntax to build the library

```
add_library(matrix
  double/matrix_constructor_double.cpp
  double/matrix_io_double.cpp
  double/matrix_miscmath_double.cpp
  double/matrix_miscop_double.cpp
  double/matrix_overload_double.cpp
  double/matrix_setters_double.cpp
  double/eigsrt_double.f
  double/pkconv_double.f)
```

CMake runs just fine, but when I try to make the project, I get the following:

```
Scanning dependencies of target matrix
[ 45%] Building CXX object src/matrix/CMakeFiles/matrix.dir/double/matrix_constructor_double.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/matrix/CMakeFiles/matrix.dir/double/matrix_io_double.cpp.o
[ 54%] Building CXX object src/matrix/CMakeFiles/matrix.dir/double/matrix_miscmath_double.cpp.o
[ 59%] Building CXX object src/matrix/CMakeFiles/matrix.dir/double/matrix_miscop_double.cpp.o
[ 63%] Building CXX object src/matrix/CMakeFiles/matrix.dir/double/matrix_overload_double.cpp.o
[ 68%] Building CXX object src/matrix/CMakeFiles/matrix.dir/double/matrix_setters_double.cpp.o
```

It just completely ignores that I've specified FORTRAN code. In autotools, this was not a problem. Also, CMake doesn't recognize that I have FORTRAN code either, i.e.

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.4.7
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dbwy/git_repo/chronusq/build
```

And if I try to specify the FORTRAN compiler manually, I get the following

```
CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER
```

Is there some function that I'm missing in my CMake to work with FORTRAN? I'm using cmake 3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying Fortran as a language for your cmake project. By default only C and C++ are enabled:

> Optionally you can specify which languages your project supports. Example languages are C, CXX (i.e. C++), Fortran, etc. By default C and CXX are enabled if no language options are given. Specify language NONE, or use the LANGUAGES keyword and list no languages, to skip enabling any languages.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/command/project.html

Something like:

```
project(foo C CXX Fortran)
```